# Process hangs waitFor() method

Tags: java, android, process, processbuilder

I am trying to get all files and folders from /data/data folder in rooted android device from java. I have command that works correctly in windows cmd:

```
adb -s <device name> shell su -c ls /data/data/
```

[image: example]

I try to execute this command in java, everything seems ok but the line

```
p.waitFor();
```

never returns.

```
public ArrayList<String> execute(String command) {
    ArrayList<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(adbPath + "adb.exe ", command);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String tmp;
        while ((tmp = in.readLine()) != null) {
            line.add(tmp);
        }
        line.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return line;
}
//adbPath = C:\Users\redra_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\
//command = -s E7AZCY935671 shell su -c ls /data/data/
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) of the method in order to understand how it works?

Comment: `adb` doesn't list files or directories. Why are you starting it at all?

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder-java.lang.String...-) says that the argument to the `ProcessBuilder` constructor is:

> "... a string array containing the program and its arguments".

and the [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) makes it clear that it means separate strings for each argument.  You have passed all of the arguments as one String. In addition, you have added a spurious space to the end of the command pathname.

I suggest that you look at [the example in the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to see how you are supposed to instantiate a `ProcessBuilder` object.

Another problem is that you appear to be calling `waitFor()` before you read the output from `adb`.  If you do that and `adb` produces more output than can be buffered in the pipe, then you will get a deadlock.  Call `waitFor()` *after* you have read all of the output.

Comment: Thanks, solution is:
Call waitFor() after you have read all of the output

Answer (score 0):

Try this method..
Any errors during the command execution has to be consumed in order to exit out of Process.Waitfor() method

```
public void executeScript(String command) {

    try {

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(command);

        InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);

        proc.waitFor();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```